# Converting TRUE/FALSE Numpy array to OpenCV Umat for HoughLines

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, hough-transform

I have a Numpy grayscale array and I set it so after a certain threshold, the value at that cell is 1, the rest are 0. I want to feed this into OpenCV's `HoughLines()` function but it wants an 8-bit, single-channel binary source image. How do I convert this so it accepts the argument?

```
gray = np.load("grayscale.npy")
binary = (gray <= 1150)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(binary, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)
```

Error thrown:

> "TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'image'"

Comment: Try passing `binary.astype(np.uint8)` to `cv2.HoughLines`.

Comment: `lines = cv2.HoughLines(binary.astype(np.uint8), 1, np.pi / 180, 200)` should fix the problem. OpenCV expects image in the type unsigned 8-bit integer format.

Comment: Worked in a dilation task with @WarrenWeckesser idea, thanks!