# Converting from numpy to cv::UMat in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, typeerror

I am using opencv on a Raspberry Pi. Everything has worked well so far, but I have reached a hiccup in trying to write the data from my camera device.

```
data = img.get_image_data_numpy()
cv2.imwrite("filepath",data)
```

The `data` gives off a `TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'`. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249728/opencv-typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-what-is-this) advice, I tried this:

```
cv2.imwrite("filepath",np.float32(data))
```

but received the same TypeError. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677536/converting-true-false-numpy-array-to-opencv-umat-for-houghlines

Comment: Joe, I tried following the advice from the link you mentioned but still get the same error.